# Bluetooth Driver not found/working Realtek 4.2 Bluetooth Adapter Hardware ID- USB\VID_0BDA&PID_B00A

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, realtek

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP 15 da1016tu laptop. At first I had trouble connecting to wifi. That has been solved. Thanks to the community. But, my Realtek 4.2 Bluetooth Adapter is not working. My Hardware ID used to be shown as USB\VID_0BDA&PID_B00A in Windows 10. Terminal says bluetooth is dead or inactive. Can anyone suggest some working solution? Thank you.

Comment: After a fresh boot, what is the output of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` please?

Comment: Nothing is shown

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running dual boot with windows 10? If so make sure you fully shut down the Windows (restart may not work - from experience) as I have had it happen to me too after using Bluetooth headphones in Windows, then restarting in Ubuntu and the Bluetooth is gone. Windows hijacks Bluetooth adapter and makes it unavailable to Ubuntu.
I solved this problem with fully shutting down windows before using Ubuntu.